# Accepting Other Peoples Invitations

Tags: google-calendar

All of a sudden, when someone sends me an invitation for an event in Google Calendar, and I accept that event, it always shows up later as not accepted and awaiting my response.  Then I click accept and it does the same thing.  Meanwhile, the person who sent the invite gets a notification every time I click it, so it is annoying to both of us!!  Note, that when I accept, it stays accepted for a while (maybe overnight) and then when I look at my calendar the next day, boom.....unaccepted. Thoughts?

Comment: How are you accepting the event invitations? On mobile or on browser?